# What happens to conjoined twins during the Snap?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

What happens to conjoined twins during the Snap? Do they both get snapped or just one twin?

Comment: Without knowing the context, this sounds like a legitimate question. Why has this been downvoted so much?

Answer (score 2):

Jon Watts, the director for *Spider-Man: Far From Home*, talked about an idea he wanted to have with twins dealing with the affects of the Blip. He comments that one of them could have been Blipped whilst another wasn’t. So presumably the same could also happen to conjoined twins, however, as far as I know no one has commented on it.

> **Was there a joke or a scene you wanted to shoot that didn’t make the final cut?**
>
> I wanted to show some animals blipping out and coming back. There was an idea about twins, where one of them disappeared and one of them got older and how that changed them. We talked about how if it’s all life in the universe, does that include bacteria? Did people get sick or really healthy because half of the bugs that live in their stomach disappeared?
>
> <sub>[Entertainment Weekly, *Spider-Man: Far From Home* director breaks down the biggest twists (and that end-credits reveal)](https://ew.com/movies/2019/07/07/spider-man-far-from-home-jon-watts-spoilers-interview/)</sub>

Presumably if one was Snapped but not the other a similar thing happened like with collateral damage from car crashes, plane crashes etc. Either the remaining one died or they “weren’t that conjoined” and managed to live.